# Angular2 Route Parameters Require DataType

Tags: routes, angular

Is it possible to set datatype requirements on the route params?

For example take the following route:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/product/:id', component: productComponent, as: 'ProductDetail'}
])
```

I would like `:id` to only match if it is a number

`/product/3` would match that route

`/product/foo` would not match the route

Comment: You could do that in the constructor of the component and redirect if it does not match your type.

Comment: Hmm... not ideal but could work for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**udpate**

WIP: feat(router): support regular expression route paths

Seems it was added recently with this PR https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13210/files and this related issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12972

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlMatcher (hopefully filled soon with some content)

**original**

This PR https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7126 should allow to do what you want

Comment: Oh.. that's looks pretty nice, rather we can have different data types, which has added in [this commit](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular/commit/9951d86d4c0216b8fa4046b5103271d4d5c9e84a)  + 1